# Sorting 1 before 10 in bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I'm sorting numerically on a specific column of a `;` separated file with:

```
sort -k3n file
```

But numbers 10 and 11 are sorted before 1. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please show example input and output files where it fails

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure that the number you're sorting on is the third character on each line? Can you provide some example data?

Comment: That worked fine at my side. Are you sure you don't have mistype in column number or some strange delimiter that sort doesn't recognize?

Comment: The file is ';' separated. But not working for me, also with the general-numeric-sort

Comment: You should mention that in the question:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your fields are separated with something else than a blank, you can use the `--field-separator` or `-t` option, like so:

```
sort -k3n -t\; file
```

Comment: @g256: You may also need to specify that only one field (at a time) is considered for the sort: `sort -k3,3n -t ';'`

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Actually the problem is a little bit more complicated since I'm sorting along two columns(first one alphabetically) with" `sort -k 1,1 -k 3,3n -t\  file`. Seems to work.

Comment: @g256: That's why I said "(at a time)". If there's a fourth column, for example, and you don't specify a stop (the `,3`) then the fourth (and subsequent) columns are included in the sort criteria.

Answer (score 1):

The -n option should do the trick. Can you check that this doesn't output the order you want?

```
echo -e "1\n10\n11\n2"|sort -n
```

Comment: It has to;) This example doesn't use more than one fields separated with a semicolon;)